# google cloud component app no longer exist

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to start working over google cloud using Nodejs using Ubuntu,
I started by installing google cloud sdk using the command

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Then I started working on google Nodejs tutorial.
But when I try to install the component [app], I got this Warning!!

```
WARNING: Component [app] no longer exists.

All components are up to date.
```

Is the app components is deprecated, and If yes, how can I deploy the my app to the cloud ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved, It seems that google changed the app component to be installed inside the package as a built-in component and removed it from components !!

So, it's activated once you installed gcloud sdk..